# GCP Dataflow JDBC to BigQuery Template replication from OCI 19C database failing with ORA-17002 error

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to replicate an OCI 19C database table to BigQuery using the GCP Dataflow "JDBC to BigQuery" Template. I have set the following parameters:

- JDBC Connection URL string: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:1521/servername
- JDBC driver Class name: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  J* DBC source SQL query: SELECT * FROM schema.tablename
- BigQuery output table: I have created a table with the same schema as Oracle's table on BigQuery and selected it
- Cloud storage paths for JDBC drivers: gs://bucketname/driverfolder/ojdbc8.jar
- Temp directory for BQ loading process: bucketname/temp
- Temp Location: bucketname/temp
- JDBC connection username: username
- JDBC connection password: password
- Max workers: 3
- Number of workers: 2
- Network: VPCNetworkName
- Subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/projectname/regions/europe-west12/subnetworks/subnetworkname

However, after running the Dataflow job for an hour, I get the following error:

`Error message from worker: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-17002: I/O error: Connection timed out, connect lapse 1115399 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms.)`

I have checked with the network admin and it seems that the connection is not established.

How can I resolve this error and successfully replicate my OCI 19C database table to BigQuery using the Dataflow "JDBC to BigQuery" Template?